# Filter the children of a has_many/belongs_to relation, and get all their parents as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, lets call them Parent and Child, where

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
end
```

For an API, I am interested in returning a list of all Child objects matching a certain condition, as well as the parent ID and their corresponding parent objects (but only the parents for the filtered children objects!) without repeating.

Something like:

```
{children: [{id: 1, parent_id: 20, attr1: x, attr2: y},...], parents: [{id: 20, attr3: z, attr4: w},...]}
```

What would the most efficient way of doing this be?

I have tried doing:

```
children = Child.eager_load(:parent).where(condition).all
parents = children.map(&:parent).uniq{|p| p.id}
```

But the use of map and uniq seems slow and wasteful?

Alternatively, I could query them separately with two SQL queries, i.e.

```
children = Child.where(condition).all
parent_ids = children.map(&:parent_id)
parents = Parent.where(id: parents_ids).all
```

However, since there might be hundreds if not thousands of different parents, this still seems somewhat inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pushing this to the database by using [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
children = Children.eager_load(:parent).where(condition).all
parents = children.pluck('distinct parent_id')
```

**edit**

I misunderstood the question. There is an alternative, but I'm not sure it's much better than running through all of them (like you show in your question) or running several queries (like you would need to do with `pluck`). You could use a `Set` to ensure uniqueness of your parent objects:

```
parents = Set.new
children = Children.eager_load(:parent).where(condition).all
children.each {|child| parents << child.parent }
```

Comment: That returns an array of all parent IDs similar to the second possibility I mentioned, right? What if I want the actual parents themselves? Should I just do `Parent.where(id: parents).all`?

Comment: Yes, it returns an array of parent ids. It replaces the `parents = children.map(&:parent).uniq{|p| p.id}` line so you'd have to re-query the db if you also wanted the parent objects. Enumerating over thousands of objects in Ruby should be fast enough for the majority of use-cases, so you may want to just eager-load the parent objects and fetch their IDs in that way if you need both their IDs and the parent object (looks like you know how to do that already :)

Comment: `parents = children.map(&:parent).uniq{|p| p.id}` actually returns the parent objects themselves (notice its **&:parent** and not **&:parent_id**), without a second SQL query (since they were already eager loaded). I'm not sure if it's very efficient though (due to the use of both map and uniq), hence my question.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh. I see. One sec, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks, the set approach seems better. I'll wait a while, to see if someone else has a better solution, but if not I'll mark this as correct.